# Cannot bypass GPG check to reinstall packages/update on Debian 7

Tags: linux, debian, gnupg, package-management, apt

```
I am trying to reinstall some packages on a debian 7.11

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)
Release:    7.11
Codename:   wheezy
```

system which I know is no longer supported but archive repositories should still work no?

I updated my /etc/sources.list with the following line:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy main
```

and everything works fine until it checks the (expired) GPG signature. I tried adding some various command line options to bypass signature verification but nothing seems to allow me to bypass gpg checks and just reinstall the packages I need.

Primary issue:

(--allow-unathenticated option has no effect, installation/update still fails.)

adding this to sources.list also doesn't work.

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://examplemachine/debian wheezy main


# apt-get --allow-unauthenticated update
Get:1 http://archive.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg [2,373 B]
Hit http://archive.debian.org wheezy Release
Ign http://archive.debian.org wheezy Release
Ign http://archive.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://archive.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en_US
Fetched 2,373 B in 3s (680 B/s)              
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org wheezy Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717 KEYEXPIRED 1668891673 KEYEXPIRED 1557241909
```

Comment: Debian 7 is out of support since 2018. First thing to do is upgrade to a supported release ASAP.

Comment: I'm aware it's out of support. There should still be a way to manage packages with an expired gpg key. That's what I'm looking for. There are other solutions that say the --allow-unauthenticated option should work in bypassing gpg checks. This is the crux of the issue, not the outdated software, but that this option fails.

Comment: The problem is not the key, it's the repos having been archived. And you shouldn't use ANY unsupported OS online, period.

Comment: You still miss my point in my last comment Nov 9 19:44. Even though it's archived, it should still be possible to run the software. Just because software becomes EOL doesn't mean you can immediately stop using it and run a newer version. I manually installed from source, that solved the problem, thanks Superuser for the super valuable suggestions.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question can you elaborate as to why? I think it shows some research effort and may be useful to others running legacy systems looking to solve their problem.

Comment: Legacy system is for the hobbyists at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ . Although not off-topic, in my opinion, question about ANY unsupported OS, unless it's about how to upgrade to a supported version/release, should be off-topic here. The mere acceptance of such questions here sort of validates such usage and that's a disservice. There are of course niche cases where niche legacy software has still valid uses but that's the exception of the exceptions. And also there's nothing wrong in using those offline but neither case is what we see here.

Comment: Try `--allow-insecure-repositories` Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/732987